# Preserve list when saving dataframe to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm currently trying to save a pandas dataframe to a csv file using `df.to_csv()`, with the three following columns:

```
index, created_at, preprocessed_text
```

Prior to saving it as a csv, each row preserves its data type, and looks like this

```
1      Thu Jan 16 13:10:16 +0000 2014  [quick, brown, fox, jumped, over, lazy, brown, dog]
```

However, as soon as its saved as a csv, all lists with length greater than 1 are converted into strings and ends up as such in the csv file.

```
1      Thu Jan 16 13:10:16 +0000 2014  "['quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumped', 'over', 'lazy', 'brown', 'dog']"
```

Lists with length 1 preserve the list data type, and get saved as just `['quick']` without `""` quotes outside of the brackets, and I'm quite confused as to why. Any guidance would be awesome.

Comment: The `""`s are most likely for escaping the `,`s or the whitespace in the lists (depending on what is used as delimiter).

Comment: `cvs` wasn't create to keep lists. Better convert list to string `"quick, brown, fox, jumped, over, lazy, brown, dog"` (using `",".join()`) before you save it. And after reading convert it back from string to list (using `split(",")`)

Comment: BTW: maybe it looks like `['quick']` without `""` but pandas may treats it as string - if you read it and try to get value from this list then probably you will have problem because it is string.

Comment: frankly, file `csv` is primitive format which treats every cell as single string - and some modules may have even option to add `" "` to all values to show it. i.e. `"1","Thu Jan 16 13:10:16 +0000 2014", "['quick']"`. If you read `csv` using module `csv` then you get  every row as list of strings - and later you have to run own code which convert strings to `int()`, `float()`, `datetime()`. But `pandas` tried to life easier and `read_csv` automatically tries to recognize type of data in columns and convert them to `int()`, `float()`, `datetime()` but it doesn't convert `list`, `dictionary`.